# What interfaces is dhcpd listening to if it has multiple?

Tags: dhcp

If the PC has more than one network interface, and there is not one defined in the comand line, which interface is the dhcpd listening to?

Comment: Which dhcpd software? There are more than one...

Answer (score 1):

I have found out it will listen on no interface if there is no statement in the `dhcpd.conf` that triggers such a behaviour.